# Find All Projects With No Tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL.

I have a Projects table. I also have a Tasks table. A Task can have a project.

I would like a query that can return a list of Projects that do not have any tasks.

Here is how I find all tasks for a project:

```
   public static IEnumerable<Task> GetAllByProject(int? projectID)
   {
         KezberPMDBDataContext db = new KezberPMDBDataContext();
         return from p in db.Tasks
                where p.ProjectID == projectID
                select p;
   }
```

Now I need to find all projects where the above query returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return db.Projects.Where(p=>!p.Tasks.Any())
```

Assuming the FK relationship exists between Project and Task and it's one to many. 
Else, let's find the project ids from all tasks and then find the projects that are outside those ids.

```
var taskProjectIds = db.Tasks.Select(t=>t.ProjectId).Distinct();
return db.Projects.Where(p=>!taskProjectIds.Any(p.Id))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with => what is this?

Comment: This would only work if Parent has a Tasks collection; even if the Parent-Tasks relationship is one-to-many, this may not be the case.

Comment: @Milo: The => is the "lambda operator". It basically separates a list of inputs from a simple expression in which they're used, and the entire thing is treated as a simple nameless (anonymous) method. You read it as "p (a Project) *goes into* the expression '!p.Tasks.Any()'".

Comment: Hmmm... A project does not have a Task in the DB, is that Okay? It is Task which has the ProjectID. But I dont get errors.

Comment: I'm assuming you have the FK relationship between Project and Task and it's one to many, ie a project may have multiple tasks. If not let me know, the query can be changed a bit.

Comment: There is a relationship with referential integrity so the first should be fine.